# Find the sum of digits of $a$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the sum of the digits of $a$ such that $$101a=6539\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^{12}+31}{1+2012^x}dx$$

I am not able to integrate the following expression. Seeing the limits as $-1,1$ I checked for odd or even function. But it is neither of them. I then tried to integrate it with the help of calculators but then they are showing something known as $\operatorname{Li}$ or polylogarithm which I don't know what is.

How to solve it$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: gcd(6539, 2012) = 503 seems suspicious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $I=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{x^{12}+31}{1+2012^x}dx.\tag{1}$

A very important formula when you have the denominator in the form of $1+a^x$, is $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx.
$$
Using this, we get $$I=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{(-x)^{12}+31}{1+2012^{-x}}dx=\int_{-1}^12012^x\dfrac{x^{12}+31}{1+2012^x}dx\tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $2I=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1x^{12}+31dx=62+\dfrac{2}{13}=\dfrac{808}{13}$ so that $I=\dfrac{404}{13}$. Then you should get $a=503\times 4=2012$ so sum of digits is $5$.